# How to add a background color to the td element when you check the checkbox in it

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to iterate through the checkboxes and give a green background color to the checkboxes which were ticked.

I have the main checkbox which disables the rest of the checkboxes so the disabled checkboxes should not have a green background color as they are disabled.

Also I will have more rows in the table and I wonder how am I suppose to avoid repeat the same block of code on every row with tons of new classes.

```js
let carParkCheckMain = document.querySelector('.car-park-check-main');
let carParkChecks = document.querySelectorAll('.car-park-check');
let tdAll = document.querySelectorAll('.access-td');

// Uncheck all checkboxes
for (let i = 0; i < carParkChecks.length; i++) {
  disable(carParkChecks[i]);
}

// Run through
for (let td of tdAll) {
  td.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    td.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (carParkCheckMain.checked) {
        for (let i = 0; i < carParkChecks.length; i++) {
          enable(carParkChecks[i]);
        }
      } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < carParkChecks.length; i++) {
          disable(carParkChecks[i]);
        }
      }
    })
  })
}


function disable(checkbox) {
  return checkbox.disabled = true;
}

function enable(checkbox) {
  return checkbox.disabled = false;
}

function greenBg(element) {
  element.classList.toggle('td-active');
}
```

```css
.td-active {
  background-color: rgb(95, 241, 95) !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered access-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" style="font-weight: 300;">Checkboxes</th>
      <td class="main-td access-td one">
        <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check-main"> main checkbox
                                    </label>
      </td>
      <td class="base-td access-td two">
        <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check" disabled> secondary checkbox
                                    </label>
      </td>
      <td class="base-td access-td four">
        <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check" disabled> secondary checkbox
                                    </label>
      </td>
      <td class="base-td access-td five">
        <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check" disabled> secondary checkbox
                                    </label>
      </td>
      <td class="base-td access-td six">
        <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check" disabled> secondary checkbox
                                    </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: _"avoid repeat the same block of code on every row with tons of new classes"_ - by not using classes/IDs to get where you need to so much in the first place. Learn to navigate to target elements based on their relation in the DOM. You want your main checkbox to only affect the other checkboxes in the same table row - so go up from the checkbox to the table row first, and then select all checkboxes that are in that row.

Comment: Like, you can f.e. use `greenBg(carParkChecks[i].parentNode.parentNode)` to toggle the class of the table cell this `carParkChecks[i]` checkbox is contained in. First `parentNode` is the `label` is is wrapped in, and second the `td`.

Comment: You're binding an event-handler inside of an event-handler; so every time the outer event (`mouseenter`) is triggered you assign another `click` event-handler to the `<td>` element; while the browser may be smart enough to optimise for this there are no guarantees, and this is likely to lead to performance problems for lower-end devices.

Comment: Also, to clarify: all checked checkboxes must have a green-background in their `<td>`, *except* when they're disabled by the main checkbox?

Comment: All checked checkboxes should have a green background color. And unchecked ones could not have a green background color. Disabled checkboxes are disabled and could not have a background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is as below, with explanatory comments in the code of that demonstration:

```js
let carParkCheckMain = document.querySelector('.car-park-check-main'),
  carParkChecks = document.querySelectorAll('.car-park-check'),
  tdAll = document.querySelectorAll('.access-td'),
  allCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('table input[type=checkbox]');


// defining a function - cellHighlight() - using an Arrow function
// expression; this function takes two arguments:
// el: Node, the node from which to navigate to the closest
//     ancestor <td> element, and
// state: an expression/assessment which will be evaluated to
//        a true/truthy/false/falsey value to determine the
//        highlighted/unhighlighted state of the <td>:
const cellHighlight = (el, state) => {
  // we use Element.closest() to navigate to the
  // closest ancestor element matching the selector; if
  // the 'el' node matches that selector then the 'el' node
  // will be returned from closest; if there is no matching
  // ancestor then this will return null:
  el.closest('td')
    // we then use Element.classList API to update the classList:
    .classList
    // we use the toggle() method to apply, or remove, the
    // 'td-active' class based on the state being truthy/true
    // (it will be added) or falsey/false (the class would be
    // removed):
    .toggle('td-active', state)
};

// binding the anonymous (Arrow) function of the EventTarget.addEventListener()
// method as the event-handler for the 'change' event, and passing in the
// Event Object ('e'):
carParkCheckMain.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  // caching a reference to the main checkbox, though as
  // we only call it once this isn't really necessary in
  // this demo:
  const main = e.currentTarget,
    // retrieving the checked/unchecked state of the
    // main checkbox for later use:
    currentState = main.checked;
  // using NodeList.prototype.forEach() to iterate over all
  // elements retrieved in the carParkChecks NodeList, and
  // passing the current element-node into the Arrow function:
  carParkChecks.forEach(
    (checkbox) => {
      // updating the enabled/disabled state to the inverse
      // of the checked/unchecked state of the main checkbox;
      // if the main checkbox is checked (main.checked === true)
      // we want to enable the checkbox.disabled state by
      // setting checkbox.disabled = false (inverse of true),
      // and vice-versa:
      checkbox.disabled = !currentState;

      // calling the cellHighlight() function, passing in the current
      // Node and the assessment by which that Node should highlighted
      // or not:
      cellHighlight(checkbox, checkbox.disabled === false && checkbox.checked)
    });
});

// again using NodeList.prototype.forEach(), and Arrow functions,
// to first bind the anonymous event-handling function to the
// 'change' event of each Node in the NodeList.
// I wasn't sure if all checkbox <td> cells - inclusing the 'main'
// checkbox - should have the 'td-active' class, if so then the
// 'carParkChecks' can be replaced with the 'allCheckboxes' NodeList:
carParkChecks.forEach(
  (checkbox) => checkbox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    // and then again using the cellHighlight() function
    // to toggle the highlight of the cell as appropriate:
    cellHighlight(e.target, checkbox.checked)
  })
);
```

```css
.td-active {
  background-color: rgb(95 241 95);
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered access-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Checkboxes</th>
      <td class="main-td access-td one">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check-main"> main checkbox
        </label>
      </td>
      <td class="base-td access-td two">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check" disabled> secondary checkbox
        </label>
      </td>
      <td class="base-td access-td four">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check" disabled> secondary checkbox
        </label>
      </td>
      <td class="base-td access-td five">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check" disabled> secondary checkbox
        </label>
      </td>
      <td class="base-td access-td six">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check" disabled> secondary checkbox
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yr8u4o39/).

Note that I removed two of your functions, the `disable()` and `enable()`, largely this was because they were unnecessary, given that it's a single line of JavaScript to do exactly the same thing; if you really wish to add those back in then, obviously do so.

One of the problems that I saw in your original posted code – as I mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69360302/how-to-add-a-background-color-to-the-td-element-when-you-check-the-checkbox-in-i#comment122593771_69360302) to the question – is that in this particular piece of code:

```
for (let td of tdAll) {
    td.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        td.addEventListener('click', () => {
          // removed for brevity
            }  
        })       
    })
}
```

You're binding an anonymous `mouseenter` event-handler on each `<td>` element, and within that event-handler you're binding another event-handler to the same element. As you never remove that inner (`'click'`) event-handler you will end up with each `<td>` having multiple `click` event-handlers which – were this more complicated code – would eventually cause performance problems on the user's device.

If you were to use a named function, and then remove that function, for example:

```
for (let td of tdAll) {
    td.addEventListener('mouseenter', () =>
        td.addEventListener('click', clickHandler)
    );
    td.addEventListener('mouseleave', () =>
        td.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler)
    );   
}
```

But this still seems a little redundant, especially when the `change` event-handler can be bound to the `input` element, and will fire in response to the mouse and space-bar events (as well as to other events fired in other assistive technologies).

One refinement I'd personally make is to use custom colours – using CSS properties – to allow for each checkbox-associated `<td>` to have its own particular colour, which involves updating the CSS to:

```
.td-active {
  background-color: var(--highlight, fuchsia);
}
```

And, in this case, updating the inline `style` attribute of the `<td>` elements to contain values such as:

```
  <td class="base-td access-td two" style="--highlight: orange">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check" disabled> secondary checkbox
    </label>
  </td>
```

For example:

```js
let carParkCheckMain = document.querySelector('.car-park-check-main'),
  carParkChecks = document.querySelectorAll('.car-park-check'),
  tdAll = document.querySelectorAll('.access-td'),
  allCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('table input[type=checkbox]');


// defining a function - cellHighlight() - using an Arrow function
// expression; this function takes two arguments:
// el: Node, the node from which to navigate to the closest
//     ancestor <td> element, and
// state: an expression/assessment which will be evaluated to
//        a true/truthy/false/falsey value to determine the
//        highlighted/unhighlighted state of the <td>:
const cellHighlight = (el, state) => {
  // we use Element.closest() to navigate to the
  // closest ancestor element matching the selector; if
  // the 'el' node matches that selector then the 'el' node
  // will be returned from closest; if there is no matching
  // ancestor then this will return null:
  el.closest('td')
    // we then use Element.classList API to update the classList:
    .classList
    // we use the toggle() method to apply, or remove, the
    // 'td-active' class based on the state being truthy/true
    // (it will be added) or falsey/false (the class would be
    // removed):
    .toggle('td-active', state)
};

// binding the anonymous (Arrow) function of the EventTarget.addEventListener()
// method as the event-handler for the 'change' event, and passing in the
// Event Object ('e'):
carParkCheckMain.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  // caching a reference to the main checkbox, though as
  // we only call it once this isn't really necessary in
  // this demo:
  const main = e.currentTarget,
    // retrieving the checked/unchecked state of the
    // main checkbox for later use:
    currentState = main.checked;
  // using NodeList.prototype.forEach() to iterate over all
  // elements retrieved in the carParkChecks NodeList, and
  // passing the current element-node into the Arrow function:
  carParkChecks.forEach(
    (checkbox) => {
      // updating the enabled/disabled state to the inverse
      // of the checked/unchecked state of the main checkbox;
      // if the main checkbox is checked (main.checked === true)
      // we want to enable the checkbox.disabled state by
      // setting checkbox.disabled = false (inverse of true),
      // and vice-versa:
      checkbox.disabled = !currentState;

      // calling the cellHighlight() function, passing in the current
      // Node and the assessment by which that Node should highlighted
      // or not:
      cellHighlight(checkbox, checkbox.disabled === false && checkbox.checked)
    });
});

// again using NodeList.prototype.forEach(), and Arrow functions,
// to first bind the anonymous event-handling function to the
// 'change' event of each Node in the NodeList:
carParkChecks.forEach(
  (checkbox) => checkbox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    // and then again using the cellHighlight() function
    // to toggle the highlight of the cell as appropriate:
    cellHighlight(e.target, checkbox.checked)
  })
);
```

```css
.td-active {
  background-color: var(--highlight, fuchsia);
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered access-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Checkboxes</th>
      <td class="main-td access-td one" style="--highlight: lime">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check-main"> main checkbox
        </label>
      </td>
      <td class="base-td access-td two" style="--highlight: orange">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check" disabled> secondary checkbox
        </label>
      </td>
      <td class="base-td access-td four" style="--highlight: #ffa">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check" disabled> secondary checkbox
        </label>
      </td>
      <td class="base-td access-td five" style="--highlight: hsl(235, 100%, 50%, .2)">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check" disabled> secondary checkbox
        </label>
      </td>
      <td class="base-td access-td six">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check" disabled> secondary checkbox
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yr8u4o39/1/).

This is, however, probably only required to support any branding or theming.

References:

- CSS:

  - [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
  - [`Event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).
  - [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`EventTarget.removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).

Answer (score 1):

```js
let carParkCheckMain = document.querySelector('.car-park-check-main');
let carParkChecks = document.querySelectorAll('.car-park-check');
let tdAll = document.querySelectorAll('.access-td');

// Uncheck all checkboxes
for (let i = 0; i < carParkChecks.length; i++) {
    disable(carParkChecks[i]);
}

// Run through
for (let td of tdAll) {
    td.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        td.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (carParkCheckMain.checked) {
                for (let i = 0; i < carParkChecks.length; i++) {
                    enable(carParkChecks[i]); 
                    td.classList.add('td-active');
                }
            } else {
                for (let i = 0; i < carParkChecks.length; i++) {
                    disable(carParkChecks[i]);
                    td.classList.remove('td-active')
                }
            }
            
        })
        
    })
}

// carParkCheckMain.addEventListener('click', () => {
    
    
// })

function disable (checkbox) {

    return checkbox.disabled = true;
}

function enable (checkbox) {
checkbox.style.backgroudColor = 'green';

    return checkbox.disabled = false;
}

function greenBg(element) {
    element.classList.toggle('td-active');
}
```

```css
.td-active {
  background-color: rgb(95, 241, 95) !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered access-table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row" style="font-weight: 300;">Checkboxes</th>
                                <td class="main-td access-td one">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check-main"> main checkbox
                                    </label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="base-td access-td two">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check" disabled> secondary checkbox
                                    </label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="base-td access-td four">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check" disabled> secondary checkbox
                                    </label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="base-td access-td five">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check" disabled> secondary checkbox
                                    </label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="base-td access-td six">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="access-table-input car-park-check" disabled> secondary checkbox
                                    </label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).